# Changes the value of XML tag which is repeating n time

Tags: shell, scripting

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StudentInfo Version="1">
<Student>
<StudentId>INS469</StudentId>
<ClassId>21</ClassId>
<Amount>100</Amount>
<Location>AA</Location>
</Student>'
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StudentInfo Version="1">
<Student>
<StudentId>INS469</StudentId>
<ClassId>21</ClassId>
<Amount>100</Amount>
<Location>AA</Location>
</Student>'
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StudentInfo Version="1">
<Student>
<StudentId>INS469</StudentId>
<ClassId>21</ClassId>
<Amount>100</Amount>
<Location>AA</Location>
</Student>`
```

Here i want to change the value of Amount using shell scripting and i want unique values only. how can i do that . please suggest.

Comment: <Amount>100</Amount>  value under Amount should be changed in all tags which are duplicated. how can i do that in unix shell scripting. Any help or suggestion would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
[sgeorge@sgeorge-ld staCK]$ cat xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StudentInfo Version="1">
<Student>
<StudentId>INS469</StudentId>
<ClassId>21</ClassId>
<Amount>100</Amount>
<Location>AA</Location>
</Student>'
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StudentInfo Version="1">
<Student>
<StudentId>INS469</StudentId>
<ClassId>21</ClassId>
<Amount>100</Amount>
<Location>AA</Location>
</Student>'
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StudentInfo Version="1">
<Student>
<StudentId>INS469</StudentId>
<ClassId>21</ClassId>
<Amount>100</Amount>
<Location>AA</Location>
</Student>

[sgeorge@sgeorge-ld staCK]$ OLDIFS=$IFS; IFS=$'\n'; COUNT=1; for i in `cat xml` ; do echo $i | sed "s/<Amount>.*<\/Amount>/<Amount>"$COUNT"<\/Amount>/g" && ((COUNT++))  ; done ; IFS=$OLDIFS
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StudentInfo Version="1">
<Student>
<StudentId>INS469</StudentId>
<ClassId>21</ClassId>
<Amount>6</Amount>
<Location>AA</Location>
</Student>'
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StudentInfo Version="1">
<Student>
<StudentId>INS469</StudentId>
<ClassId>21</ClassId>
<Amount>14</Amount>
<Location>AA</Location>
</Student>'
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StudentInfo Version="1">
<Student>
<StudentId>INS469</StudentId>
<ClassId>21</ClassId>
<Amount>22</Amount>
<Location>AA</Location>
</Student>
```

OR (If you want a real custom value for Amount) do like following:

```
[sgeorge@sgeorge-ld staCK]$ cat amount.txt 
121213424525
1213125435
1313145357460
988783784332
82990190231932

[sgeorge@sgeorge-ld staCK]$ OLDIFS=$IFS; IFS=$'\n'; COUNT=1; for i in `cat xml` ; do echo $i | grep '<Amount>' >/dev/null && AMT=$(tail -1 amount.txt) && sed -i "/^$AMT$/d" amount.txt && echo $i | sed "s/<Amount>.*<\/Amount>/<Amount>"$AMT"<\/Amount>/g" || echo $i ; done ;  IFS=$OLDIFS
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StudentInfo Version="1">
<Student>
<StudentId>INS469</StudentId>
<ClassId>21</ClassId>
<Amount>82990190231932</Amount>
<Location>AA</Location>
</Student>'
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StudentInfo Version="1">
<Student>
<StudentId>INS469</StudentId>
<ClassId>21</ClassId>
<Amount>988783784332</Amount>
<Location>AA</Location>
</Student>'
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StudentInfo Version="1">
<Student>
<StudentId>INS469</StudentId>
<ClassId>21</ClassId>
<Amount>1313145357460</Amount>
<Location>AA</Location>
</Student>
```

**EDIT**

```
OLDIFS=$IFS; IFS=$'\n'; COUNT=1; for i in `cat xml` ; do echo $i | grep '<Amount>' >/dev/null && AMT=$(tail -1 amount.txt) && sed -i "/^$AMT$/d" amount.txt && echo $i | sed "s/<Amount>.*<\/Amount>/<Amount>"$AMT"<\/Amount>/g" || echo $i ; done > /tmp/xml_output.xml;  IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Comment: Yea thanks a lot for the desired output. how can i redirect this output to some tempfile.

Comment: Hi suku, First one is fine. Second one which u have given OLDIFS=$IFS; IFS=$'\n'; COUNT=1; for i in `cat xml` ; do echo $i | grep '<Amount>' >/dev/null && AMT=$(tail -1 amount.txt) && sed -i "/^$AMT$/d" amount.txt && echo $i | sed "s/<Amount>.*<\/Amount>/<Amount>"$AMT"<\/Amount>/g" || echo $i ; done ;  IFS=$OLDIFS. This out put is not getting properly. XML file is not coming in Formatted way. i have included ur code and redirected to >>test.xml file. can you please check on this.

Comment: OR (If you want a real custom value for Amount) do like following:           The second want is what is needed , can you please tell me why its giving me junk data.

Comment: bash: echo<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>: command not found
bash: echo<StudentInfo Version="1">: command not found
bash: echo    <Student>: command not found
bash: echo        <StudentId>INS469</StudentId>: No such file or directory
bash: echo        <ClassId>21</ClassId>: No such file or directory
        <Amount></Amount>
bash: echo        <Location>AA</Location>: No such file or directory
bash: echo    </Student>: No such file or directory

Comment: you need to execute the oneliner exactly the way I put in answer. Make sure all spaces in command. Also this one liner is based on your `sample xml` file you pasted in question.

Comment: Im having doubt at the last part. Its not redirecting to some samplefile. Im getting empty file. and on the screen output as:                 bash: echo<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>: command not found
bash: echo<StudentInfo Version="1">: command not found
bash: echo    <Student>: command not found
bash: echo        <StudentId>INS469</StudentId>: No such file or directory
bash: echo        <ClassId>21</ClassId>: No such file or directory
        <Amount>4</Amount>
bash: echo        <Location>AA</Location>: No such file or directory
bash: echo    </Student>: No such file or directory

Comment: you are redirecting in a wrong way.. redirect in the same way i mentioned.

Comment: How to keep that in a shellp script rather then running through onliner

Comment: #!/bin/ksh
max=`grep "<Amount>" xml|wc -l`
rm numtest.txt
#echo $max
i=0
while ((i <= $max ))
do
echo $i >> numtest.txt
((i= i+1))
done

OLDIFS=$IFS; IFS=$'\n'; COUNT=1; for i in `cat xml` ; do echo $i | grep '<Amount>' > /dev/null  && AMT=$(tail -1 numtest.txt) && sed -i "/^$AMT$/d" numtest.txt && echo $i | sed "s/<Amount>.*<\/Amount>/<Amount>"$AMT"<\/Amount>/g" || echo $i ;done > /tmp/xml_output.xml;  IFS=$OLDIFS

Comment: can you please check where im going wrong. the above code which i have put in script. but amount value is not changing

Comment: You need to have a file called `amount.txt` like i showed in answer with amounts. Each line will get deleted upon usage with `sed -i "/"$AMT"/d" amount.txt`. Also, I am not familiar with `ksh`. I am using `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that the "..." tags are on a single line, you can use the following awk one-liner (the xml text to change is stored in "file"):

```
awk -v AMOUNT=1 '/<Amount>.*<\/Amount>/ { print "<Amount>" AMOUNT++ "</Amount>" ; next } ; { print }' file
```

To read the values from a "amounts_file.txt":

```
awk -v AMOUNT_FILE="amounts_file.txt" '/<Amount>.*<\/Amount>/ { getline AMOUNT < AMOUNT_FILE ; print "<Amount>" AMOUNT++ "</Amount>" ; next } ; { print }' file
```

After the end of the amount file, the values of Amount will be incremented from the last value of the file.

Comment: Here my output should be unique for ex: amount values can be like this: 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5..... like this the set is repeating.. if we do AMT++ values wil be repating. I want unique values for Amount tab

Comment: The AMOUNT value used in the first script is initialised to 1 at the beginning of the script (-v AMOUNT=1). It completely ignores the actual field value. The AMOUNT++ will always increase until you reach very high values and therefore will not repeat.
The second script will not repeat if the list of value in amount_file is big enough and does not repeat.

Comment: JEAN-- Thank you so much. It worked the way you said and The way i wanted to.